# PHP imagecopy with transparent background

Tags: php, png, imagecreatefrompng

I use this code to create an image from another png image, the background is black by default. My question is how to set a transparent background?

```
$input = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');
$output = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 50);

imagecopy($output, $input, 4,0, 8,8, 8,8);
imagecopy... etc.

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($output);
```

Is there a easy way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sets the transparent color in the given *image*.

```
int imagecolortransparent ( resource $image [, int $color ] )
```

Here's the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php)

Comment: Yes! This worked: `$black = imagecolorallocate($output, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($output, $black);` before the imagecopy

Comment: what if I want transparent to be the transparent color?

Comment: Everything that gets copied over draws its transparent colors as black on the destination image. I don't want to lose the pixels that were already black in the source image.

Answer (score 12):

Since the PHP function `imagecopymerge` doesn't work with the Alpha channel, you'll want to use the function from the first comment on this page `imagecopymerge_alpha`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

Just have the transparent image as the base and merge it together with the image you need.

I've tried it out and it works fine for a project of mine.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: This didn't work for me, when I copy a source image with transparency, all the transparent colors in the source image are drawn as black onto the destination image.

Answer (score 5):

None of the solutions worked for me, it would always convert transparent pixels on the source image to black on the destination image. What worked was changing imagecopy/imagecopymerge/imagecopymerge_alpha to imagecopyresampled and just passing the same width and height twice.

```
    //Create destination image.
    $png = imagecreatetruecolor(1024, 1024);
    imagealphablending($png, false);
    imagesavealpha($png, true);
    //Make destination image be all transparent.
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($png, 0, 0, 0, 127); //127 means completely transparent.
    imagefill($png, 0, 0, $color);

    //Load source image.
    $png2 = imagecreatefrompng($sourceurl);
    imagealphablending($png2, false);
    imagesavealpha($png2, true);
    $sizex = imagesx($png2);
    $sizey = imagesy($png2);

    //Copy to destination and save to file.
    imagecopyresampled( $png, $png2, 
    0, 0,
    0, 0, 
    $sizex, $sizey, 
    $sizex, $sizey);
    imagepng($png, "result.png");
```

Comment: This also worked for me with cutting parts of gif images containing some fancy transparency (idk why it was problem only with few images only).
Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

```
imagealphablending($input, true);
imagesavealpha($input, true);

imagealphablending($output, true);
imagesavealpha($output, true);
```

Comment: This is incorrect, bending should be set to `false` before running `imagesagealpha` .

Answer (score 1):

Full credit goes to: 
http://consistentcoder.com/combine-a-transparent-png-image-on-top-of-another-image-with-php

The following code will overlay the foreground image onto the background image while **preserving the transparency of the overlay**:

```
//set the source image (foreground)
$sourceImage = 'table.png';

//set the destination image (background)
$destImage = 'create-a-surreal-head-of-tree-photo-manipulation.jpg';

//get the size of the source image, needed for imagecopy()
list($srcWidth, $srcHeight) = getimagesize($sourceImage);

//create a new image from the source image
$src = imagecreatefrompng($sourceImage);

//create a new image from the destination image
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg($destImage);

//set the x and y positions of the source image on top of the destination image
$src_xPosition = 75; //75 pixels from the left
$src_yPosition = 50; //50 pixels from the top

//set the x and y positions of the source image to be copied to the destination image
$src_cropXposition = 0; //do not crop at the side
$src_cropYposition = 0; //do not crop on the top

//merge the source and destination images
imagecopy($dest,$src,$src_xPosition,$src_yPosition,
          $src_cropXposition,$src_cropYposition,
          $srcWidth,$srcHeight);

//output the merged images to a file
/*
 * '100' is an optional parameter,
 * it represents the quality of the image to be created,
 * if not set, the default is about '75'
 */
imagejpeg($dest,
    'combine-a-transparent-png-image-on-top-of-another-image-with-php-01.jpg',
    100);

//destroy the source image
imagedestroy($src);

//destroy the destination image
imagedestroy($dest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or propably

```
int imagesavealpha($img,true);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php

Comment: imagesavealpha just sets if the alpha channel information should be saved when writing out the imagedata (into file or buffer)