# Image with transparanent background becoming white when added with imagecopymerge

Tags: php, image, png, transparency

I'm using `imagecopymerge` to place an image on top of another image, however, when I do so, the transparent part of the image becomes white, which isn't what I am after. So the images I have are the below as the background:
[image]

And the image I am adding on top of it, with transparent background, is this:
[image]

This, however, (along with the rest of my code) results in the area around the circle, and within the boundaries being white:
[image]

The code I am using at the moment to inject the value is:

```php
    $magical = imagecreatefrompng('Magical.png');
    imagecopymerge($img, $magical, 366, 135, 0, 0, 32, 32, 100);
```

Research has said I should try using things like `imagealphablending` or `imagecopy` instead of `imagecopymerge`, but that didn't work. I've also found references to trying `imagecolortransparent` and `imagecolorallocate` but that didn't work either. So, for example, neither of these attempts worked:

```php
    $magical = imagecreatefrompng('Magical.png');
    $white = imagecolorallocate($output, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($magical, $white);
    imagecopymerge($img, $magical, 366, 135, 0, 0, 32, 32, 100);
// or this attempt
    $magical = imagecreatefrompng('Magical.png');
    imagealphablending($img, true);
    imagealphablending($magical, true);
    imagecopymerge($img, $magical, 366, 135, 0, 0, 32, 32, 100);
```

What am I missing here? How do I ensure that when the image is added to the other its transparency is retained?

Comment: Is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728508/php-imagecopy-with-transparent-background?

Comment: What was the result for imagealphablending?

Comment: On the official PHP documentation a user submitted an answer which might be useful to you. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787

Comment: I saw that, @hppycoder, and as mentioned, `imagecolortransparent` didn't do anything to help.

Comment: A, what appears to be, [identical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUXTU.png) image, @HassaanAli .

Comment: Did you try the `imagecopymerge_alpha` from the PHP docs - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787?

Comment: I just tried changeing `imagecopymerge` to `imagecopymerge_alpha` and the image isn't created at all, @hppycoder . Just a white page.

Comment: To clarify, you implemented the function `imagecopymerge_alpha` per the documentation and tried using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pulled your images into my local machine and used the imagecopymerge_alpha function listed on the PHP Documentation - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787

```
<?php

function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){
    // creating a cut resource
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);

    // copying relevant section from background to the cut resource
    imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);

    // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource
    imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);

    // insert cut resource to destination image
    imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
}

$img = imagecreatefrompng('baseImage.png');
$magical = imagecreatefrompng('overlay.png');
imagecopymerge_alpha($img, $magical, 366, 135, 0, 0, 32, 32, 100);

imagepng($img, "./test.png");
```

[image]